# RVM fails to install Ruby 1.9.3 on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby.  Somewhere along the line I feel like I broke some ruby requirements / libraries.  I have no idea what I'm doing.  Please help.

gcc is installed (as well as xcode)

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

rvm seems to be installed

```
$ rvm -v

rvm 1.25.25 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

ports seems to be installed

```
$ port version
Version: 2.2.1
```

attempting to install ruby fails

```
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p545.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
ERROR: '/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

So I try the recommended fix and realize something is wrong with my brew installation

```
$ brew doctor
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

I decided that I ruined my dafault osx ruby installation and decided to fix this by upgrading to Mavericks.  Now gcc and rvm versions return the same as before and I get these other results:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$ port version
-bash: port: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you don't have write access to the /bin directory for the install (ergo the error message); try again with 'sudo rvm reinstall 1.9.3'.

Comment: I believe my initial osx ruby install was ruined.  I fixed this by upgrading to Mavericks but still having issues.  See updated question above.